# Styled component: Nested rules in different files does not work

Tags: css, reactjs, web-applications, styles, styled-components

I've defined a file with a styled *textarea* but I want to use a different piece of style for a React component, at the end I am not able to change the style for the particular tag.

Here below the textarea file

```
const Container = styled.div`
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
`;

const Label = styled(B1)`
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
`;

const StyledTextArea = styled.textarea`
  width: fill-available;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  ::placeholder {
    color: red;
  }
`;

const TextArea = ({ label, placeholder, input, rows }) => (
  <Container>
    {label && <Label>{label}</Label>}
    <StyledTextArea rows={rows} {...input} placeholder={placeholder} />
  </Container>
);

TextArea.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  input: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default TextArea;
```

Here below there is my component in which I'd like to change the *font-size* component but it does not work

```
const TextBox = styled(TextArea)`
  > StyledTextArea {
    font-size: 3rem !important;
  }
`
class SingleGuestForm extends Component {
<Field
  name="Nested Rules"
  label="Test with nested rules"
  rows="3"
  component={TextBox}
/>
}
```

It seems that the rule defined in the TextBox is ignored by the style engine. Do you know why it happens? I tried different solution (surrounding StyledTextArea with curly braces, etc) but nothing happen even if in the official doc the solution I've implemented should work ([here](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#can-i-nest-rules)). Thank you so much for any help

Comment: You'll want to import the `StyledTextArea` component and use it within the `TextBox` component. Both components MUST be styled components in order for this to work. See [referencing other components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components) documentation for an example. Styled components creates dynamic class names, so you can't reference the styled component by its `StyledTextArea` name.

Comment: I've tried importing StyledTextArea but nothing changed, could you provide me a working solution? I've tried the same solution as in the example, with the curly braces

Comment: You may also need to bump the selector specificity in order to "override" the text area's styling. I see you tried using `!important` already, so you're sort of on the right track. See [Issues with Specificity](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#issues-with-specificity) and [Pseudo elements, selectors and nesting (last note)](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting). You should avoid `!important` still.

Comment: I've used it just because of that, but the result is the same

Comment: Guys, perhaps the problem is that TextArea it is not a styled component, does it?

Comment: I think this might be helpful since you are trying to refer to your `StyledTextArea` component: [Referring to other components](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components)

Comment: I've already seen it but I do not understand why it is not working with my example, could you help me please?

Comment: Ad the end I tried all solutions you guys provided but the behaviour is the same, the CSS property isn't overridden